# Sublimerge won't work on scss file

Tags: sublimetext3, package-control

I installed Sublime text 3 and Sublimerge but for some reason it cannot compare .scss file. I am not sure what I did wrong because everything was default. But if I copy and paste both files into Untitle tab to compare, it works.

Is there some settings I supposed to change?

**UPDATE**

Here are my steps:

1. Download Sublime text 3 for Mac
2. Install package control
3. Install Sublimerge Pro
4. Open .scss file from github reop locally
5. Download another folk of repo in .zip and expand to different folder
6. Open same .scss file in the folked repo
7. Compare View
8. The new window opens but there is no diff although they obviously are different

Comment: Please describe the exact steps you took, in detail, to compare two files. Without knowing what you did, it's impossible to troubleshoot.

Comment: Where is that "folk" repo ? For me scss is working, try disabling all plugins except Sublimerge Pro

Comment: It's in a parallel folder outside of current repo. Like ./mainrepo vs ./folkedrepo. So nothing special. This is fresh install and nothing else in the plugins.